# Insert (changeable) html into modal using javascript’s ES6 Classes

Tags: javascript, arrays, es6-class, insertadjacenthtml

I need some help implementing a javascript feature on this website that I’m developing.

The website have a section with some pictures of different persons. I want to open a modal with content related to that specific person, every time one clicks a picture. So, the content of the modal changes accordingly to the picture clicked.

So far I can make it work but can’t change the information accordingly to the picture I click on. I’m struggling to come up with a solution to change that html.
I’m using ES6 Classes and an array of objects to dtore the information about every person but I can’t find a way to make it work and not even sure if that’s the most efficient way.
The code, as it is, opens and closes the modal but doesn't isert any html because it's not complete, as I explained.
Any ideas?
Thank you for your help.

**Here is my html:**

```html
<!-- members section -->
<section class="content-members section members hidden" id="section-2">
    <ul class="list-members">
        <li class="list-item list-item-content" data-id="1">
            <div class="item-primary">
                <div class="item-image">
                     <img loading="lazy" src="img/hr3_hi.png" alt="Adolfo Mesquita Nunes" class="image-hr">
                <div class="item-hovering"></div>
                    <div class="item-content">
                        <div class="text">
                            <h2>hvjhvjhv kjgkgkg kjhkjhkjh</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="list-item list-item-content" data-id="2"> … </li>
        <li class="list-item list-item-content" data-id="3"> … </li>
        <li class="list-item list-item-content" data-id="4"> … </li>
        <li class="list-item list-item-content" data-id="5"> … </li>
        <li class="list-item list-item-content" data-id="6"> … </li>
        <li class="list-item list-item-content" data-id="7"> … </li>
        <li class="list-item list-item-content" data-id="8"> … </li>
        <li class="list-item list-item-content" data-id="9"> … </li>
        <li class="list-item list-item-content" data-id="10"> … </li>
        <li class="list-item list-item-content" data-id="11"> … </li>
        <li class="list-item list-item-content" data-id="12"> … </li>
    </ul>
</section>

<!-- members popup -->
<div class="popup-members">
    <!-- 
    <div class="members-hero">
        <div class="members-hero-photo">
            <img src="" alt="members photo">
        </div>
        <div class="members-hero-content">
            <h1 class="members-hero-name"></h1>
            <p class="members-hero-presentation"></p>
            <a href="" class="members-hero-email"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    -->
    <button class="members-hero-btn">&larr;</button>
</div>
```

**And javascript:**

```js
const popupMembers = document.querySelector('.popup-members');
const members = document.querySelectorAll('.list-item');
const membersPage = document.querySelector('.members-hero');
const closeMembersPage = document.querySelector('.members-hero-btn');

// EVENTS AND FUNCTIONS
// individual members information --------------------
const membersList = [
  {
    id: '1',
    name: 'fulano nunes',
    img: 'img/hr1_hi_NoBG.png',
    present: 'Minim sint mollit cillum ullamco proident occaecat ex Lorem consequat ea. Deserunt eiusmod enim elit exercitation. Minim eu anim in elit consequat. Sit nisi ea sint consectetur laborum nostrud. Tempor laborum ea culpa do eu exercitation irure labore nulla excepteur dolor.',
    email: 'example@email.com'
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    name: 'fulana joaquina',
    img: 'img/hr2_hi.png',
    present: 'Minim sint mollit cillum ullamco proident occaecat ex Lorem consequat ea. Deserunt eiusmod enim elit exercitation. Minim eu anim in elit consequat. Sit nisi ea sint consectetur laborum nostrud. Tempor laborum ea culpa do eu exercitation irure labore nulla excepteur dolor.',
    email: 'example@email.com'
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    name: 'fulana abrantes',
    img: '/img/hr3_hi.png',
    present: 'Minim sint mollit cillum ullamco proident occaecat ex Lorem consequat ea. Deserunt eiusmod enim elit exercitation. Minim eu anim in elit consequat. Sit nisi ea sint consectetur laborum nostrud. Tempor laborum ea culpa do eu exercitation irure labore nulla excepteur dolor.',
    email: 'example@email.com'
  },
  {
    id: '4',
    name: 'fulana carvalho',
    img: '/img/hr4_hi.png',
    present: 'Minim sint mollit cillum ullamco proident occaecat ex Lorem consequat ea. Deserunt eiusmod enim elit exercitation. Minim eu anim in elit consequat. Sit nisi ea sint consectetur laborum nostrud. Tempor laborum ea culpa do eu exercitation irure labore nulla excepteur dolor.',
    email: 'example@email.com'
  },
  {
    id: '5',
    name: 'fulana maria',
    img: '/img/hr5_hi.png',
    present: 'Minim sint mollit cillum ullamco proident occaecat ex Lorem consequat ea. Deserunt eiusmod enim elit exercitation. Minim eu anim in elit consequat. Sit nisi ea sint consectetur laborum nostrud. Tempor laborum ea culpa do eu exercitation irure labore nulla excepteur dolor.',
    email: 'example@email.com'
  },
  {
    id: '6',
    name: 'fulana peniche',
    img: '/img/hr6_hi.png',
    present: 'Minim sint mollit cillum ullamco proident occaecat ex Lorem consequat ea. Deserunt eiusmod enim elit exercitation. Minim eu anim in elit consequat. Sit nisi ea sint consectetur laborum nostrud. Tempor laborum ea culpa do eu exercitation irure labore nulla excepteur dolor.',
    email: 'example@email.com'
  },
  {
    id: '7',
    name: 'fulana cabana',
    img: '/img/hr7_hi.png',
    present: 'Minim sint mollit cillum ullamco proident occaecat ex Lorem consequat ea. Deserunt eiusmod enim elit exercitation. Minim eu anim in elit consequat. Sit nisi ea sint consectetur laborum nostrud. Tempor laborum ea culpa do eu exercitation irure labore nulla excepteur dolor.',
    email: 'example@email.com'
  },
  {
    id: '8',
    name: 'fulano nunes',
    img: '/img/hr8_hi.png',
    present: 'Minim sint mollit cillum ullamco proident occaecat ex Lorem consequat ea. Deserunt eiusmod enim elit exercitation. Minim eu anim in elit consequat. Sit nisi ea sint consectetur laborum nostrud. Tempor laborum ea culpa do eu exercitation irure labore nulla excepteur dolor.',
    email: 'example@email.com'
  },
  {
    id: '9',
    name: 'fulano nunes',
    img: '/img/hr9_hi.png',
    present: 'Minim sint mollit cillum ullamco proident occaecat ex Lorem consequat ea. Deserunt eiusmod enim elit exercitation. Minim eu anim in elit consequat. Sit nisi ea sint consectetur laborum nostrud. Tempor laborum ea culpa do eu exercitation irure labore nulla excepteur dolor.',
    email: 'example@email.com'
  },
  {
    id: '10',
    name: 'fulana bárbara',
    img: '/img/hr10_hi.png',
    present: 'Minim sint mollit cillum ullamco proident occaecat ex Lorem consequat ea. Deserunt eiusmod enim elit exercitation. Minim eu anim in elit consequat. Sit nisi ea sint consectetur laborum nostrud. Tempor laborum ea culpa do eu exercitation irure labore nulla excepteur dolor.',
    email: 'example@email.com'
  },
  {
    id: '11',
    name: 'fulana carvalho',
    img: '/img/hr11_hi.png',
    present: 'Minim sint mollit cillum ullamco proident occaecat ex Lorem consequat ea. Deserunt eiusmod enim elit exercitation. Minim eu anim in elit consequat. Sit nisi ea sint consectetur laborum nostrud. Tempor laborum ea culpa do eu exercitation irure labore nulla excepteur dolor.',
    email: 'example@email.com'
  },
  {
    id: '12',
    name: 'fulana cabana',
    img: '/img/hr12_hi.png',
    present: 'Minim sint mollit cillum ullamco proident occaecat ex Lorem consequat ea. Deserunt eiusmod enim elit exercitation. Minim eu anim in elit consequat. Sit nisi ea sint consectetur laborum nostrud. Tempor laborum ea culpa do eu exercitation irure labore nulla excepteur dolor.',
    email: 'example@email.com'
  }
];

// render members --------------------
class MembersIND {
  constructor(id, name, img, present, email) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.img = img;
    this.present = present;
    this.email = email;
  };

  // render member
  renderMember (img, name, present, email) {
    let html =  `<div class="members-hero">
                  <div class="members-hero-photo">
                      <img src="${this.img}" alt="members photo">
                  </div>
                  <div class="members-hero-content">
                      <h1 class="members-hero-name">${this.name}</h1>
                      <p class="members-hero-presentation">
                          ${this.present}
                      </p>
                      <a href="mailto:example@example.com" class="members-hero-email">${this.email}</a>
                  </div>
                </div>`;
    membersPage.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', html);
  };
};
// const someMember = new MembersIND();
// someMember.renderMember();

// members control --------------------
class MembersGEN {  
  constructor() {
    members.forEach(m => {m.addEventListener('click', this.openModal.bind(this))});
    closeMembersPage.addEventListener('click', this.closeModal.bind(this));
  };

  // show modal  
  openModal (e) {
    // detect member
    const memberId = e.target.closest('.list-item').getAttribute('data-id');
    // show modal
    popupMembers.style.display = 'block';
    // fade-in
    setTimeout(() => {
      popupMembers.style.opacity = '1';
    }, 100);
  };

  // close modal  
  closeModal() {
    // hide modal
    popupMembers.style.opacity = '0';
    // fade-out
    setTimeout(() => {
      popupMembers.style.display = 'none';
    }, 500);
  };
};
const member = new MembersGEN();
```

Comment: Indeed, your code is not complete. You are not creating instances of the first class, not calling its render method, ...etc. You cannot expect the content to change if your code is just not doing it. If you have a question about an **attempt** at doing it, and it fails, then focus your question on that. Now it is too broad.

Comment: Well, the code to create an instance and to call the remderMember method on that instance is there, as a comment, however, there’s no point because I can’t figure out how to create a specific instance (Person) based on twelve sources (Persons). I have a working code using event hendlers and an array of objects, pretty simple. I’m going to stick with that code for now and come back later to my ES6 Classes solution. Thank you for your time.